# Highcharts - Area Chart - Stacking with series containing negative and positive values

Tags: javascript, highcharts

We are upgrading from Highcharts 2.3.2 to current version, and we have some problems with stacked area charts. The problem is that `stacking:'normal'` behavior is not as expected when we have series that contain both positive and negative values.

JsFiddles:

[Highcharts 2 - *Desired Behavior*](https://jsfiddle.net/tjmpe6se/6/), **see chart 2**

[Highcharts Current - *Unwanted Behavior*](https://jsfiddle.net/tjmpe6se/7/), **see chart 2**

We have managed to fix this issue in charts that contain series with either only positive or only negative values, by using the `stack` attribute on each series (see **chart 1** in second JsFiddle).

Can anyone point us to a direction on resolving this issue?

Comment: Problem illustration is available here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/s2RmJ.png

Comment: I think that it is more complicated problem of how to deal with stacked series with negative values. You can find more information about this issue in Highcharts 3.0.5v changelog: http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/changelog#3-0-5-bug-fixes

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński We have already tracked the fix in 3.0.5 changelog, i think you are refering to **[issue 1910](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1910).** The problem is that this fix actually introduces bugs to our charts.. I was kind of hoping to find a way to bring back the previous functionality without having to change the way that chart series are built (ps: we own a Highcharts commercial license)

Comment: I have posted your issue on a Highcharts github: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5671

Comment: Thanks for posting that. I hope it can be resolved

Answer (score 1):

[I was able to workaround](https://codesandbox.io/s/13rxlqryn3) it with the help of explanation given in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41107037/148271), though in my workaround at June, 19 14:40 and June, 19 16:20, there is a single negative point of Con with positives before and after it. This can cause issue when you have multiple series of such kind i.e. which one to stack above the other will be a question.